# Access Crypto.Com API with R (translate from Python)

Tags: python, r, api, hash

I promise I tried my best but I just couldn't get this to work.

Here's the exact python code from the API Website:
https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/spot/index.html?python#digital-signature

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import json
import requests
import time

API_KEY = "API_KEY"
SECRET_KEY = "SECRET_KEY"

req = {
  "id": 11,
  "method": "private/get-order-detail",
  "api_key": API_KEY,
  "params": {
    "order_id": "337843775021233500",
  },
  "nonce": int(time.time() * 1000)
};

# First ensure the params are alphabetically sorted by key
paramString = ""

if "params" in req:
  for key in sorted(req['params']):
    paramString += key
    paramString += str(req['params'][key])

sigPayload = req['method'] + str(req['id']) + req['api_key'] + paramString + str(req['nonce'])

req['sig'] = hmac.new(
  bytes(str(SECRET_KEY), 'utf-8'),
  msg=bytes(sigPayload, 'utf-8'),
  digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest()
```

I'm not sure if I got anywhere close, but here's what I got but isn't working -- unfortunately I can't for the life of me tell WHAT I'm getting wrong as I just get a generic error message.  For example, maybe I'm not formatting my UNIX time the way they want it..  Any ideas, please help!

```
library(httr)

library(digest)

API_KEY <- "FOO"
SECRET_KEY <- "BAR"

base <- "https://api.crypto.com/v2/"

API.Balance <- function() {
  method <- "private/get-account-summary"
  
  hash<-paste0(method,11,API_KEY,"",ceiling(as.numeric(Sys.time())))
  print(hash)
  hash<-hmac(SECRET_KEY,hash,algo="sha256")
  print(hash)
  
  call1 <- paste0(base,method,"?api_key=",API_KEY,"&sig=",hash)
  print(call1)
  get.req <- GET(call1)
  get.req.txt <- content(get.req, "text",encoding = "UTF-8")
  return(fromJSON(get.req.txt, flatten = TRUE))
}

API.Balance()
```

This returns:

```
[1] "private/get-account-summary11FOO5"
[1] "ed19ac611d5342f2cbd93a52c70ce884bbcdb9a4062572b013a494fd2c50fd03"
[1] "https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary?api_key=FOO&sig=ed19ac611d5342f2cbd93a52c70ce884bbcdb9a4062572b013a494fd2c50fd03"
$code
[1] "100001"

$msg
[1] "SYS_ERROR"
```

So I gave it a few hours but I'm just scratching my head.  I know it's something simple I'm missing.  Could someone please help me translate the Python approach to R?  Thank you.

Comment: The unix time is in milliseconds in python and in seconds in R. Set the same time in both python and R and see whether you get the same output from `hmac` (consider also the `serialize` argument in the R function).  You didn't show how you performed the API call in python; it looks like that you showed just how to build the request.

Comment: Correct, the Python code I didn't write it's straight from the API. Which is part of the frustration. If only they provided the string output and I could compare my hash to theirs... It's also very strange that the ID seems arbitrary, could be any number I like? As each method doesn't have its own ID defined. But that's crazy, because how would cryptocom know what random I'd number I chose in order to compare the hash I sent to the hash they generated on their server?

Comment: By the way, how do I convert the r Unix time into milliseconds?  Another interesting observation is that I get a SYS ERROR and not an authentication error, you'd think it would be an auth error if it was my hashing to blame? I wish R was more adopted as I find it infinitely easier to work with than Python for stats type work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out and for the good of humanity I think I'll post my solution!  Complete with sorting params.

I was using a GET instead of a POST and I totally forgot to reinject the hash into the "req" object after it was calculated (and other minor things).  Anyway, several hours of tearing out my hair, so you don't have to, you get this:

```
API.Balance <- function() {
  endpoint <- "private/get-account-summary"
  
  req <- list(
    id=11, #This doesn't matter, you define it
    method=endpoint,
    api_key=API_KEY,
    params=list(
      currency="USDT" #leave blank if no params
    ),
    nonce=floor(as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000)
  )
  
  req$params <- req$params[order(names(req$params))]
  
  params<-""
  for(i in 1:length(req$params)) {
    params=paste0(params,names(req$params)[i])
    params=paste0(params,req$params[[i]])
  }

  hash<-paste0(req$method,
               req$id,
               req$api_key,
               params,
               req$nonce)

  hash<-hmac(SECRET_KEY,
             hash,
             algo="sha256")

  req<-c(req,sig=hash)
  
  response <- POST(url=paste0(base,endpoint),
                     body=req,
                     encode="json")
  
  response.txt <- content(response, "text",encoding = "UTF-8")
  return(fromJSON(response.txt, flatten = TRUE))
}

API.Balance()
```